# Android Studio Java MediaPlayer plays only the first second of audio and then stops

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have MediaPlayer play a roughly two minute long mp3 audio, however only the first second is played then the player stops. I've tired both mp3 and wav formats. Here's my code:

```
package com.pi.audiodemo;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = (MediaPlayer) MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dumb);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Style-7 apparently using MediaPlayer.create() automatically does that. adding it returns a compile error. "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `MediaPlayer` within the `onCreate` function. So it will be deleted right after function returns. Try the following code:

```
package com.pi.audiodemo;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = (MediaPlayer) MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dumb);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick and the audio now plays all the way but the playback is laggy and slow (as if it's playing with 0.5x speed). How do I fix this?